# Getting Error inflating class fragment error while using view binding in fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewbinding

Since `Kotlin 1.8` made view binding compulsory so I implemented it in main activity and fragment. But I am getting error inflating the class fragment

Here is the main activity class. I think there is an error in inflating the main layout because of view binding. I have initialized navContoller which was working fine before adding code in home fragment

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    lateinit var viewModel: MandirViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val mandirRep = (application as MandirApplication).repository

        val viewModelFactory = MandirViewModelFactory(mandirRep)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this , viewModelFactory).get(MandirViewModel::class.java)

        navController = findNavController(R.id.navContainer)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.homeFragment , R.id.notificationsFragment , R.id.favouriteFragment , R.id.settingsFragment))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController , appBarConfiguration)
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)     

   }
}
```

Here is the home fragment to call the repository for API call. I think the error here is inflating the layout. Might be because of viewbinding

```
  class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mandirViewModel: MandirViewModel
    private lateinit var mandirAdapter: MandirAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater , container , false)

        mandirViewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
        mandirAdapter = MandirAdapter()

        binding!!.rvMandir.apply {
            adapter = mandirAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        }


        mandirViewModel.mAndirs.observe( viewLifecycleOwner , Observer {
            it.let { response->
                mandirAdapter.differ.submitList(response.data)

            }

        })

        return view
    }    
}
```

This is the application class. I have used it to initialize repository using instance of Retrofit class

```
class MandirApplication : Application() {

    lateinit var repository: MandirRepository

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        initialize()
    }

    private fun initialize() {

        val mandirService = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(MandirAPI::class.java)
        repository = MandirRepository( mandirService , applicationContext)
    }
}
```

Here is the XML file for the main activity. I have used frame layout as i read here that fragment view requires frame layout to move across fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navContainer"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.997"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the XML file of the home Fragment. The is an error inflating this layout in the home fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rvMandir"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the error log. Don't know is shows viewModel not initialized. It also shows issue in inflating layout
Please help

```
2023-05-03 15:38:17.103  1931-1931  AndroidRuntime com.example.mandirapp E FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                              
Process: com.example.mandirapp, PID: 1931 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mandirapp/com.example.mandirapp.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.mandirapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.mandirapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.mandirapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.mandirapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.mandirapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
   at com.example.mandirapp.ui.MainActivity.getViewModel(MainActivity.kt:25)
   at com.example.mandirapp.ui.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:34)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
   at com.example.mandirapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:45)
   at com.example.mandirapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:39)
   at com.example.mandirapp.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:30)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
2023-05-03 15:38:17.104  1931-1931  AndroidRuntime com.example.mandirapp E at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. They could of left synthetics alone. I can't get my fragments to work either. I am up voting this question

Comment: - Camp NerdResolved navController error with this code appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.homeFragment , R.id.notificationsFragment , R.id.favouriteFragment , R.id.settingsFragment)) val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navContainer) as NavHostFragment navController = binding.navContainer.getFragment<NavHostFragment>().navController setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration) binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because you have to return your inflated view in onCreateView() method. In your case it's `binding.root`. Like this:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

  private lateinit var mandirViewModel: MandirViewModel
  private lateinit var mandirAdapter: MandirAdapter
  private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater , container , false)

    mandirViewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
    mandirAdapter = MandirAdapter()

    binding!!.rvMandir.apply {
        adapter = mandirAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    }


    mandirViewModel.mAndirs.observe( viewLifecycleOwner , Observer {
        it.let { response->
            mandirAdapter.differ.submitList(response.data)

        }

    })

    return binding.root
  }

}
```

Comment: i did that but didn't resolve the error. I changed fragment to fragment container view so the viewmodel not initialized error was gone

Comment: Resolved navController error with this code
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.homeFragment , R.id.notificationsFragment , R.id.favouriteFragment , R.id.settingsFragment))
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navContainer) as NavHostFragment
navController = binding.navContainer.getFragment<NavHostFragment>().navController
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)